# Triangle max sum using depth first search

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have the classic problem with a triangle and need to get the max path. I am allowed to move from (i,j) to (i,j-1), (i, j+1), (i+1,j)

**Example input**:

```
      1
    1 2 3
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and the **maximum path** is the sum of (1) + (2 + 3) + (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) + (2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7). I am not allowed to move on a node twice

I know how to solve this using DP but this problem has been shown to us at the Artificial Intelligence class and the solution it needs is using DFS/GBFS

How is it possible to solve this problem using DFS? Only recursive came to my mind but it's not near close to DFS.

I am representing the input as a graph, so for the following

```
    1
  2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

I have the following graph
1 -> {3}, 3 -> {2, 4, 7}, 4 -> {3, 8} etc

I was thinking of doing a recursive function, MaxSum(node) and start from node 1 and do something like that

return Max(MaxSum(neighbour_1), MaxSum(neighbour_2), ..., MaxSum(neighbour_n)) + node

where each neighbour_i is unvisited neighbour

But where does the DFS part come in?
Also, how could I solve this problem using GBFS?

I am not interested in code or something, only algorithmic explanations

Comment: The first step is to write down your problem in such a way that someone not knowing it can figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: I don't understand the question; what exactly is _the classic problem with a triangle_? Is seems as if there is also some objective value involved; please provide an example.

Comment: I have updated the problem now. It was a mistake before. I have also added a sample input

Comment: On your example input, wouldn't the maximum path be : (1) + (2 + 3) + (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) + (2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) ?

Comment: Oh, yea, my mistake. You're correct

Comment: In fact, DFS is a recursive algorithm; it can be implemented either using the call stack or a user-defined stack, but the approach remains recursive nevertheless. DFS and recursion are not mutually exclusive concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> But where does the DFS part come in?

The graph you have is acyclic and the problem you are trying to solve is [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths) (after transforming the node weights to edge weights). The general solution requires you to use DFS to find a topological order but in your case you know an easy topogical order, the one just like in your example:

```
    1
  2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

You use this order for second part - the DP solution. So in a way, you are skipping the `DFS` part.

You could explicitly run DFS for the first path and it could give a different topological order (depending on how you traverse the edges) but it's just a waste of effort.

Also for the second part, instead of performing the DP you could use BFS level by level to update the neighbors of the elements in the current level. But again it doesn't make much sense since using DP would give you the same results and would even be cheaper.